# php: what exactly does setting session.gc_max_lifetime = 0 mean?

Tags: php, session, garbage-collection

Does setting

`session.gc_max_lifetime = 0`

mean (in the core implementation) that the garbage collector *never* or *immediately* deletes the affected session in case of a gc-method-call?

Comment: Please highlight your code parts. I can't edit it, due to the fact, that my change would only affect 4 symbols. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This normally means that the session will die immediately. But it depends on other options like `session.gc_probability`. If it's set to 0, the session won't expire automatically. If it's set to 1 (which is the default) it will check and expire the session.

Comment: Yes, it depends on gc_propabiltiy, thats what i ment with "...in case of a gc-method call.". the question is - when the garbage collector is called, will it immediately delete the session when gc_max_lifetime is set to 0, or never.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer. It will expire directly.

Comment: If you want to have a long running session, you can also set a very high value to it. Or disable the `gc_probability`. :-)